# How to make a button in a notification 'do something'

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to make a simple stopwatch app that will display the time in a notification and give you a couple buttons that will allow you to start and stop the stopwatch.

How do I add a button to a notification? And how do I 'point' that button to a certain function?

Heres a picture of what I was thinking:
[image]

```
    actionIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    timerNotification.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Start", actionPendingIntent);
```

This is what I currently have. Where in the intent would I put the function I want to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Add Action to the notification and assign a `pendingintent`

Comment: I have updated my question. Where in  the pending intent do I put the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom your notification layout,you can use setContent() function with a RemoteViews of your custom layout.

```
Remote View mRemoteView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_general);
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_battery)
        .setContent(mRemoteView)
        .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

To handle an notification button onClick event, you need to use separate PendingIntents(made from Intents with differecnt actions) for every button. Later in onReceive() you just check action of incoming Intent & execute different code depending on that. Remember to assign your Listener on manifest.

```
Intent generalIntent = new Intent(context, GeneralReceiver.class);
generalIntent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, ACTION_GENERAL);
PendingIntent generalPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, generalIntent, 0);
mRemoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNotificationGeneral, generalPendingIntent);
public static class GeneralReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             //Your code here
        }
    }
```